# unable to install realm on linux for react-native

Tags: react-native, realm

Unable to install the realm for react-native. It always gives some error irrespective of the different commands i use to install it. It always gives some version mis-match error.
when trying to install using  - sudo npm install --save realm --target=7.10.0

```
Getting following error
> lzma-native@3.0.3 install /home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build && node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://node-pre-gyp.addaleax.org/lzma-native/lzma_native-v3.0.3-node-v51-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for lzma-native@3.0.3 and node@7.10.0 (node-v51 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://node-pre-gyp.addaleax.org/lzma-native/lzma_native-v3.0.3-node-v51-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for lzma-native@3.0.3 and node@7.10.0 (node-v51 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.3-node-v51-linux-x64/lzma_native.node" "--module_name=lzma_native" "--module_path=/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.3-node-v51-linux-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native
gyp ERR! node -v v7.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.3-node-v51-linux-x64/lzma_native.node --module_name=lzma_native --module_path=/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.3-node-v51-linux-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v7.10.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.3-node-v51-linux-x64/lzma_native.node --module_name=lzma_native --module_path=/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.3-node-v51-linux-x64' (1)
gyp ERR! configure error stall: info lifecycle lzma-native@3.0.3~install: Faile
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.3-node-v51-linux-x64/lzma_native.node" "--module_name=lzma_native" "--module_path=/home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.3-node-v51-linux-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ambujeshtripathi/React-Project/DM/LMSReactNative/node_modules/lzma-native
gyp ERR! node -v v7.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN react-native-drawer-layout@1.3.2 requires a peer of react@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-drawer-layout@1.3.2 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-drawer-layout-polyfill@1.3.2 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-push-notification@3.0.1 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.33 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-tab-view@0.0.70 requires a peer of react@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-tab-view@0.0.70 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.13 requires a peer of react@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.13 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-tab-view@0.0.69 requires a peer of react@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-tab-view@0.0.69 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-test-renderer@16.0.0-alpha.12 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0-alpha.12 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! lzma-native@3.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build && node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the lzma-native@3.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ambujeshtripathi/.npm/_logs/2017-11-27T05_43_48_055Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/addaleax/lzma-native/issues/45 is useful.

Answer (score -1):

I solve it by typing:

`sudo -s`

and then:

`sudo npm install --save realm`